# Responsive Designs a basic understanding

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

since the hype is Responsive Web Design, and I already know how to write it, I am just here to clarify a few questions of my own before I keep doing something wrong if I am.

If we set a divs style like so:

```
div {
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
   background: #000;
   margin: 10px 5px;
    }
```

Now to be responsive the way we want would we do-

```
div {
   background:#000
    }
 @media screen and(max-width:1200px) {
    div {
      width:300px;
      height:300px;
      margin: 20px 5px;//Question is here
        }
     }
 @media screen and(max-width:720px) {
     div {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    margin: 20px 5px;//question is here
         }
     }

 @media screen and(max-width:360px) {
      div {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
          }
     }
```

The question is in face if we set the margin or any style that is going to be the same for an for greater width or minimum width do we keep assigning it do can we leave it at that? So if we set the margin at 20px 5px will that stay with it until 1200px? And the same goes for reverse will it stay the same until it gets to 360px and then change?

It's just a question that has been bothering me.

Comment: You still need a selector inside your media queries, i.e. to what do those styles apply?

Comment: Oh lol I'm sorry yes I know this that is my bad. I was just trying to write this as quickly as possible before bed. Thanks for the catch though, my actual css does have the selectors inside the media queries

Answer (score 2):

The `max-width:1200px` media query will apply to *all sizes below*, meaning that you won't need to re-apply the same values again in the `720px` one.

In comparison:

```css
@media screen and (max-width:1200px) {
    /* applies to all viewports below 1201px */
}

@media screen (min-width:721px) and (max-width:1200px) {
    /* only applies to viewports above 720px and below 1201px */
}
```

In conclusion, seeing as the values in your second (`720px`) media query rule is the same as the bigger one, they are applied twice (not necessary).

Comment: Ok. So it won't be necessary. That is what I was looking for. So if set to the higher media query then we won't need to constantly add it in lower queries unless we want it to change. Correct

Answer (score 0):

i think use percentage value to margin and width. You can avoid the resizing problem